# Spark ML VectorAssembler() dealing with thousands of columns in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classification, pipeline

I was using spark ML pipeline to set up classification models on really wide table.  This means that I have to automatically generate all the code that deals with columns instead of literately typing each of them. I am pretty much a beginner on scala and spark. I was stuck at the  VectorAssembler() part when I was trying to do something like following:

```
val featureHeaders = featureHeader.collect.mkString(" ")
//convert the header RDD into a string
val featureArray = featureHeaders.split(",").toArray
val quote = "\""
val featureSIArray = featureArray.map(x => (s"$quote$x$quote"))
//count the element in headers
val featureHeader_cnt = featureHeaders.split(",").toList.length


// Fit on whole dataset to include all labels in index.
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().
  setInputCol("target").
  setOutputCol("indexedLabel")

val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler().
  setInputCols(featureSIArray).
  setOutputCol("features")

val convpipeline = new Pipeline().
  setStages(Array(labelIndexer, featureAssembler))

val myFeatureTransfer = convpipeline.fit(df)
```

Apparently it didn't work.  I am not sure what should I do to make the whole thing more automatic or ML pipeline does not take that many columns at this moment(which I doubt)?

Comment: This still does not work for me.  I think my input data frame is fine.  I can easily create a labeled point to feed into MLlib, but not for the ML pipeline.  Please advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out one way, which is not very pretty.  It is to create vector.dense for the features, and then create data frame out of this.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
val myDataRDDLP = inputData.map {line => 
 val indexed = line.split('\t').zipWithIndex 
 val myValues = indexed.filter(x=> {x._2 >1770}).map(x=>x._1).map(_.toDouble)
 val mykey = indexed.filter(x=> {x._2 == 3}).map(x=>(x._1.toDouble-1)).mkString.toDouble
 LabeledPoint(mykey,  Vectors.dense(myValues))
}
 val training = sqlContext.createDataFrame(myDataRDDLP).toDF("label", "features")
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use quotes (`s"$quote$x$quote"`) unless column names contain quotes. Try

```
val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler().
  setInputCols(featureArray).
  setOutputCol("features")
```

Comment: Thanks, but using featureArray did not work either.  It gave this error:

WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 28.0: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 28.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 28.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: It has nothing to do with this. It looks like you have malformed data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will revisit my input data. =)

Answer (score 0):

For pyspark, you can first create a list of the column names:

```
df_colnames = df.columns
```

Then you can use that in vectorAssembler:

```
assemble = VectorAssembler(inputCols = df_colnames, outputCol = 'features')
df_vectorized = assemble.transform(df)
```